# Failed to execute goal org.openjfx:javafx-maven-plugin defaullt cli

Tags: java, maven, javafx, intellij-plugin

I am working on a  project in intellij with javafx and have this error when executing:
Failed to execute goal org.openjfx:javafx-maven-plugin:0.0.1:run (default-cli) on project uebung11: Error

This is my **pom file**:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>hbgm.spengergasse</groupId>
    <artifactId>uebung11</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <maven.compiler.source>12</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>12</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-base</artifactId>
            <version>12</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-controls</artifactId>
            <version>12</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-fxml</artifactId>
            <version>12</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-swing</artifactId>
            <version>12</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-graphics</artifactId>
            <version>12</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.8.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <release>11</release>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
                <artifactId>javafx-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>0.0.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <mainClass>uebung11.hbgm.spengergasse.App</mainClass>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

**App. java**

/**
 * JavaFX App
 */
public class App extends Application {

```
private static Scene scene;

public App() throws IOException {
}

@Override
public void start(Stage stage) throws IOException {
    scene = new Scene(loadFXML("primary"));
    stage.setScene(scene);
    stage.show();
}

static void setRoot(String fxml) throws IOException {
    scene.setRoot(loadFXML(fxml));
}

private static Parent loadFXML(String fxml) throws IOException {
    FXMLLoader fxmlLoader = new FXMLLoader(App.class.getResource(fxml + ".fxml"));
    return fxmlLoader.load();
}
Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("/sample.fxml"));

public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch();
}
```

}

I have already searched for a solution and read all the questions that have been already published but I couldnt solve this problem so I would be very happy if you could help  me.

Comment: Hi Jery, did you manage to fix this? I'm struggling with the same problem.